# Beamer: How to change the color of itemized bullet points inside alert blocks, but not the color of alerted text?

Tags: beamer, color

Consider the following LaTeX code for a simple beamer presentation. The code is saved in a file called `presentation.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{alertblock}{Beware!}
         \begin{itemize}
            \item This is \alert{important!}
         \end{itemize}
      \end{alertblock}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When compiled from the command line via the command `pdflatex presentation`, a 1-page pdf file is produced, which shows:

[image: The actual output]

How can I change the color of the bullet point to blue, while keeping the color of the word "important" red, so that the output looks like this:

[image: The desired output]

If it makes the solution easier, it is OK if the title's color is changed to blue too, i.e. if the color of the word "Beware!" is changed to blue together with the color of the bullet point.

Comment: Change `\begin{alertblock}{Beware!}` by  `\begin{block}{Beware!}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `local structure` colour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{alertblock}{Beware!}
          \setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=structure.fg}
         \begin{itemize}
            \item This is \alert{important!}
         \end{itemize}
      \end{alertblock}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]